# How to include all data for the day until midnight in DB2

Tags: c#, datetime, db2

I am very new to DB2.

I have noticed that when I do a script like this all data for 2020-02-25 00:00:00 is excluded. I would like to see all data upto midnight 2020-02-25 00:00:00.

My script is like so

```
SELECT * FROM FMSLIBLE.VVSREXPORTDELIVERIES WHERE FINALDELIVERYDATETIME >= '2020-02-24 00:00:00' AND FINALDELIVERYDATETIME <= '2020-02-25 00:00:00' AND ISPOSTFLIGHT <> 'Y'
```

[image: My Result Set]

However when I change the script to this it works but excludes any records for 25th midnight (basically the only circled in the image above).

```
SELECT * FROM FMSLIBLE.VVSREXPORTDELIVERIES WHERE FINALDELIVERYDATETIME >= '2020-02-24 00:00:00' AND FINALDELIVERYDATETIME <= '2020-02-25 11:59:00' AND ISPOSTFLIGHT <> 'Y'
```

The FinalDeliveryTime column is a Timestamp in the database and it is calculated form a decimal values like this

```
TIMESTAMP(DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(DIGITS(A.EMDLVA), 'DDMMYY')),TIME(TO_TIMESTAMP(DIGITS(DEC(A.EMDLVT,4)),'HH24MI')) )       
                        END AS FINALDELIVERYDATETIME
```

Comment: AFAIK your first `WHERE` clause is already correct, and should in fact include Feb-25 precisely at midnight.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Thanks for your comment. I would like to include all data for 25th until midnight.  I dont seem to see this in the result set.

Comment: I get your question, what I'm saying is that your SQL already looks correct to me, barring some peculiarness of DB2 which I don't know.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I get it now. Thank you. Yes this must work in SQL. It is something to do with DB2 I think.

Comment: is your column a timestamp? Maybe there are milliseconds that make trouble, what happens with 00:00:01

Comment: And what is the column FINALDELIVERYTIME, why is it null when time is '00:00:00'? Is this a View, which columns are calculated?

Comment: @Abe Try to output the `FINALDELIVERYDATETIME` column values with the following function: `TO_CHAR(FINALDELIVERYDATETIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.FF12')`.

Comment: @Turo - Hi Turo, thanks for looking into this. Yes the column is a timestamp and I have updated my question now showing how the FinalDeliveryTime is calculated.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein - Does this mean the FinalDeliveryTime will be a char instead of DateTime, I am assigning this to properties in C# so if it is char i have to do conversion and all. Ideally I would like to avoid this.

Comment: @Abe This is a test to check, if you really have second fraction not equal to 0 or not. Your SQL client may not show this part of `Timestamp` value.

Answer (score 0):

@Turo might be rigth - you are using DBeaver to query it and DBeaver often suppresses the sub-second part of the tinmestamp. So you might not see the full time information. Check it out from command line or configure DBeaver to show the full timestamp.

Easy check - run following command in DBeaver

```
values current timestamp
```

You should get this format

```
2020-02-24-18.01.57.834000
```

If not check the timestamp format seetings in DBeaver

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for looking into this. When I run the above script I get the following
2020-02-25 08:56:23

Comment: So the microsecond part is omitted because of DBeaver settings - check out Settings / Properties - Result Sets - Data formats. It works in my environment and i got a German installation so I do not have more details here - but it is some setting there

Answer (score 0):

Select all timestamps for date.

```
select * from mylib.mtable where date(mytimestamp) = current date
```